# Three.js : How to put pictures on each side of the cube?

Tags: three.js

I would like you to give any idea to solve my problem.
Now, I am trying to have a 3-D cube on the browser with three.js.
The cube will have these pictures as textures for each side of them (like a dice).
[image]

The problem is that the cube does not have them as textures, though my browser shows no errors.
Could you have any solutions?
Here are codes below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>CamTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="myCanvas">
        
    </section>

    <section id="textarea">
        <h1>CamTest</h1>
    </section>
    
    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

#myCanvas{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: gray;
}

#textarea{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS(three.js)

```
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
const section = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

window.addEventListener('load', init());

function init(){
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    section.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        5000
    );
    camera.position.x=0
    camera.position.y=2;
    camera.position.z=5;


    const geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3,1,0.5);
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const urls = [
        "./pics/Adobe_1.png", "./pics/Adobe_2.png",
        "./pics/Adobe_3.png", "./pics/Adobe_4.png",
        "./pics/Adobe_5.png", "./pics/Adobe_6.png"
    ]
    const materials = urls.map(url => {
        return new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: loader.load(url)
        })
    });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geo, materials);

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x345fff);
    light.position.set(2,4,4);
    scene.add(light);

    cube.position.set(1,1,1);
    scene.add(cube);
    
    


    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

[image]

The cube to be generated will have each pictures on each of their side.

Comment: If your objective is to throw a dice, see: [Crafting a dice roller with ThreeJS and CANNON](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2023/01/25/crafting-a-dice-roller-with-three-js-and-cannon-es/)

Comment: You render your scene just once, and it happens before textures are loaded (loading is asynchronous). Make a render loop.

Comment: dear prisoner849,  I am so sorry for my poorest understanding: do you mean this like below?   ```urls.forEach((url)=>{
        console.log(url);
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    });```

Comment: dear danny-365csi-engelman, thank you so much for your kind support and a url.  I just want to have each picture on each face of the cube.  So sorry for my terrible explanation.

Comment: Try to change this line: `renderer.render(scene, camera);` in your code snippet of the question, into this: `renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {renderer.render(scene, camera)});`

Comment: dear prisoner849, thank you so much. I did it the way I wanted to work!